# Máscara Percentual

Tags: jquery, jquery-mask-plugin

Necessito de uma máscara de percentual com a biblioteca `jQuery Mask Plugin v1.5.4`.

O que eu estou tentando fazer é que o usuário possa informar um valor de -99,99 até 99,99.

Estou tentando assim:

```
$("#edtPercentual").mask("99,99%");

$("#edtPercentual").on("blur", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().length == 1 ? $(this).val() + '%' : $(this).val();
    $(this).val( value );
});
```

Como podem ver, não trata muita coisa. Como faço que eu consiga colocar negativo e também como faço para aparecer o "%" em qualquer situação, no código acima não aparece o percentual quando o valor possui duas(2) casas decimais.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizando a base da resposta de @LucasCosta, alterei para a forma que eu necessitava:

- Removido o % da máscara e atribuído aos gatilhos blur e focus

```js
$('.numero').mask('Z#9V##', {
    translation: {
  'Z': {
    pattern: /[\-\+]/,
    optional: true
  },
  'V': {
    pattern: /[\,]/
  },
  '#': {
    pattern: /[0-9]/,
    optional: true
  }
 }
});

$(".numero").on('blur',function(){
 if($(this).val().length > 0)
    $(this).val( $(this).val() + '%' );
}).on('focus',function(){
   $(this).val( $(this).val().replace('%','') ); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.3/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<input class="numero" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o *translate*:

```js
$('.numero').mask('Z99,99%', {
  translation: {
    'Z': {
      pattern: /[\-\+]/,
      optional: true
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.3/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<input class="numero" />
```

Comment: A edição deveria ser uma nova resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa seria fazer assim:

```js
jQuery(function($){
  $("#edtPercentual").keyup(function() {
    //Obter o primeiro caractere digitado
    var temp = $(this).val().charAt(0);
    //Verificar se o primeiro caractere inserido é '-'
    if (temp == '-'){
        //Aplica a máscara para números negativos
        $("#edtPercentual").mask("-99,99%");
    }
    //Verificar se o primeiro caractere inserido é número
    else if (temp.charAt(0).match(/\d/)){
        //Aplica a máscara para números positivos
        $("#edtPercentual").mask("99,99%");
    }
    //Caso o primeiro caractere inserido seja um caractere inválido limpa o value do campo
    else {
       $("#edtPercentual").val('');
    }
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.3/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
Percentual <input type="text" id="edtPercentual">
```

Answer (score 0):

eu encontrei essa forma aqui de fazer usando o mask Jquery:

```js
$('#percent').mask('##0,00%', {reverse: true});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="percent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function setPercentageMask() {
    let input = $('.percent');
    input.mask('##0,00', {reverse: true});
    input.bind("change keyup", function() {
        isBetweenPercentage($(this));
    });
}

function isBetweenPercentage(input) {
    let myNumber = (input.val()) ? parseFloat(input.val()) : 0;
    (myNumber.isBetween(0, 100.00)) ? myNumber : input.val('100,00');
}

if (typeof(Number.prototype.isBetween) === "undefined") {
    Number.prototype.isBetween = function(min, max, notBoundaries) {
            var between = false;
            if (notBoundaries) {
                if ((this < max) && (this > min)) between = true;
            } else {
                if ((this <= max) && (this >= min)) between = true;
            }
            return between;
    }
}

setPercentageMask();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js" integrity="sha512-pHVGpX7F/27yZ0ISY+VVjyULApbDlD0/X0rgGbTqCE7WFW5MezNTWG/dnhtbBuICzsd0WQPgpE4REBLv+UqChw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<input name="text" class="percent">
```